# spring access property file values using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: spring

How do I access the property file values if I am using the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`

Is there a way to get it by using `x = context.getBean("") and then x.getProperty("firstName")`?

I want to use it in main class, so I am not looking to inject it using @Value

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to access it as bean.

For that in your context file define your properties bean under utils.
something like:

```
<util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:server.properties" />
```

Make sure you have necessary schemas in `xmnls` and `xsi` declarations which are

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

and for `xsi`

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
```

now all you have to do is load the bean to `Properties` object

```
Properties x = context.getBean("myProps");
```

And you're good to go..!

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

```
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(new ClassPathResource("your_file_path"));
```

Or you can use [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).